# Construction of concurrent or parallel lines from a parallelogram (proof by vectors)

Tags: vectors

I have a problem with this probably easy exercise on vectors. Any help would be great.

Let ABCD be a parallelogram. The line parallel to AB intersect  BC and AD in points Q and S, respectively. The line parallel to BC intersects  AB and DC in points P and R, respectively. 
Show that the lines AC, PQ and RS either intersect in a point or they are parallel.